# How to connect to a postgres database in a docker container?

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, docker-container

I setup my django and postgres container on my local machine and all working fine. Local server is running, database running but I am not being able to connect to the created postgres db.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:13.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=my_user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=my_password
      - POSTGRES_DB=my_db

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

I tried this command:
`docker exec -it container_id psql -U postgres` 
error:
`psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist`

I am very new to Docker.

Comment: You set the username and password to `my_user`/`my_password` in the configuration; do those credentials work?

Comment: i suppose it works because postgres database is successfully created with those configurations, but i want to connect to this database and not being able to connect ? @DavidMaze

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using the username and the password you provided in your docker-compose file. Try this and then enter `my_password`:

```bash
docker exec -it container_id psql -U my_user -d my_db --password
```

Check [the official documentation](https://docs.postgresql.fr/15/app-psql.html) to find out about the PostgreSQL terminal.

Comment: got this error: `OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: exec: "export PGPASSWORD=my_password; psql -U my_user -d my_db": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
`

Comment: Assuming your container is up and running, try `docker exec -it container_id psql -U my_user -d my_db --password` and then enter `my_password`. Should work fine! And note that it is more convenient to replace `container_id` by `$(docker ps | awk '/postgres/ {print $1}')`.

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to add, in your compose file you're not exposing any ports for the db container. So it will be unreachable via external sources (you, your app or anything that isn't ran within that container).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add `environment` to project container.

```
   environment:
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_NAME=my_db
      - DB_USER=youruser
      - DB_PASS=yourpass
   depends_on:
      - db
```

add this before `depends_on`

And now see if it solves

Answer (score 0):

You should add ports to the docker-compose for the postgres image,as this would allow postgres to be accessible outside the container

```
- ports: 
   "5432:5432"
```

You can checkout more here [docker-compose for postgres](https://geshan.com.np/blog/2021/12/docker-postgres/)